# Do you get experience for mobs your minions kill in Torchlight?

Tags: torchlight

As an alchemist or whatever the sorcerer character is called in torchlight, I purchased the skill where I have 3 imps and my pet cat running with me at almost all times. That means that I rarely feel like I kill mobs personally, as mostly I'm doing AOE attacks or buffing my minions.

Do I get full experience for mobs my minions kill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I played a character that was heavily biased towards summoning minions, and you do indeed gain full XP for anything your minions kill.  Some people played almost [completely minion focused](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showpost.php?p=4070751&postcount=3) and still got tons of XP.

The Alchemist gets some *crazy* OP area attacks (Ember Strike comes to mind) late in the game though, to the point where if you have enough mana regen you can just obliterate entire floors without anyone ever coming anywhere close to you.

Comment: Yeah, I only get touched anymore when I misclick and run in the middle of a mob mob. I'm level 22, and since I was playing on easy I'm starting anew on hard. =)

Comment: And my misclicking problem is now fixed since I saw the tip that I stay put if I hold down shift and attack...