# Do I gain fame when my pet kills mini-bosses?

Tags: torchlight

Do I still gain fame when my pet kills mini-bosses? Even if I didn't do any damage to them?

Comment: Seeing as pet/minion kills nets you exp, gold, and other bonuses, I don't see how it wouldn't give fame as well. Especially seeing as there's builds focused entirely on minions. 

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42532/do-you-get-experience-for-mobs-your-minions-kill-in-torchlight

Comment: Ok thank you.... I've been sending my pet to town just to get him out of battle so he doesn't ks me xD

Comment: That would be brutal. I've played through TL1 multiple times, as well as TL2, and I've never had a pet steal my fame. I'm positive the game treats it as an extension of the playe.r